# LINUX: Failed to pkg-config on libcryptsetup

Tags: linux, pkg-config, luks

Can someone help me with this error:

```
pkg-config --cflags  -- libcryptsetup
Package libcryptsetup was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libcryptsetup.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'libcryptsetup' found
```

My server:

Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.8 (Maipo)

```
  ~> rpm -qa | grep cryptsetup
cryptsetup-libs-2.0.3-6.el7.x86_64
cryptsetup-2.0.3-6.el7.x86_64
```

I am not really sure how to set the ENV var for PKG_CONFIG_PATH.

Thanks James

Comment: 1) See if there's a "libcryptsetup.pc" file anywhere on your filesystem (for example, "/usr/lib64/pkgconfig/libcryptsetup.pc").  2) If there isn't, try installing cryptsetup-devel.  3) Definitely post back what you find.

Comment: There is no cryptsetup-devel for OEL linux or RHEL, din't see any libcryptsetup.pc anywhere but i found  ```  ~> locate libcryptsetup
/usr/lib64/libcryptsetup.so.12
/usr/lib64/libcryptsetup.so.12.3.0
/usr/lib64/libcryptsetup.so.4
/usr/lib64/libcryptsetup.so.4.7.0```

Comment: Q: So what exactly was it you were trying to do that gave you the "pkg-config --cflags ... No package 'libcryptsetup' found
" error message?  You clearly have cryptsetup installed ... but it's looking for some "libcryptset" *package*.  What exactly is "it"?  What command are you running/goal you're trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

Now you can use `dnf --enablerepo=crb install cryptsetup-devel` to install that on CentOS9-stream.

base on https://centos.pkgs.org/9-stream/centos-crb-x86_64/cryptsetup-devel-2.4.3-5.el9.x86_64.rpm.html